# Nissan Pulsar 2001 N16 Door actuator problem

Tags: nissan, door, pulsar, actuator

The front left hand door of my Nissan Pulsar 2001 N16 won't open.  I'm in Australia with RHD, so this is my passenger door.  The key turns in the lock and I can hear the bolt in action.  Same with the lock tab on the inside of the door.  Lifting the exterior handle does nothing, pulling the interior catch does nothing.

Because I can't open the door, I can't get access to the screws for removing the interior door trim.

Looking for advice on removing the trim without overly mutilating it, or where to drill with a hole cutter to minimise damage until I can replace it from a wrecker.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Do the interior and exterior door handles feel normal to operate?

Comment: How are the screws hidden, are they hidden by the body of the car, or is the seat in the way?

Comment: @HandyHowie they're hidden by the bulk of the dash at the front of the door and by the pillar at the back of the door.  Visible when door is open (based on other side)

Comment: The handles can move, they just have no effect.